# Usar metodos de la clase String en otras clases

Tags: java

Al ejecutar un case dentro de un switch, da un error con la linea declaración del objeto de la clase Viaje, y luego vuelve a aparecer al declarar el constructor dentro de la clase Viaje cuando uso métodos de strings, que puedo hacer para ejecutar los métodos de string en las clases sin los errores.
En consola me aparece: java.lang.NullPointerException en ambos caso.

```
public Viaje(int plaz, String cOrigen, String cDestino, double importe, int num) {
            super();
            this.plaz = plaz;
            this.cOrigen = cOrigen;
            this.cDestino = cDestino;
            this.cod = cOrigen.substring(0,2);;
            this.importe = importe;
            this.num =num;
        }
```

Comment: He borrado la coma que aparece en la linea del substring y siguen dando los mismos errores por consola.

Comment: Aquí hay un `;` de más: `this.cod = cOrigen.substring(0,2);;` Si sigue fallando, por favor, agrega a la pregunta la traza completa del error que imprime. El problema podría ser también `cod`, no aparece en ese método, supongo que es un miembro de la clase o del padre declarado correctamente ¿? Quizá conviene que muestres la clase completa para tener una visión de conjunto.

Comment: Por favor incluye el código en el que usas esta clase Viaje, pues es el que arroja el NPE

Comment: COrigen es null. Es lo único que puede provocar un NPE ahí